# Firebase storage best practices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a flat database structure as is suggested, but I'm not sure if the same practice should be used for storage as well.

It's not too much trouble for me to just do:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(someUID).child(someNode1).child(someNode2) and so on and so on
```

But is this the best practice? Should I try to flatten out the storage structure as well?

---

EDIT BELOW

Would it be safe to say that it's okay to have something like this, then:

```
root
  |
  'uid1
      |
      'Group 1
            |
            'Thousands of pictures
      |
      'Group 2
            |
            'Thousands of pictures
      .
      .
      .
  |
  'Thousands more UIDs
```

In other words, breadth and depth of storage doesn't matter, corret?

Comment: All of the issues such as denomalization and flattening that apply to Firebase database have nothing to do with Firebase storage. You should introduce hierarchy into storage if you want to do things like more easily browse what you have in storage, or be able to easily delete entire subtrees. Beyond that, there is no real problem with having a single flat top level with thousands of items.

Answer (score 2):

You won't see any performance improvements by flattening your Firebase Storage structure. This is because the way you retrieve data from Firebase Storage (only the requested files are downloaded) is very different to that of the Realtime Database (all child data is returned for some data request).

Therefore, you can structure the Storage data any way that makes the most sense to your use case.

Comment: Yes, my answer still applies. If you're only retrieving a few items from a folder at a time it doesn't matter how many other items are in the folder.